# How to limit the number of restarts in minikube K8s

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I want to limit the maximum number of restarts for a pod. I have restartPolicy as always and I don't want to change it to Never,but want to limit the number of restarts.Is it possible to do so somehow ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. What are you trying to achieve? Provide more details.

Comment: I just don't want service to restart like 900 or 1000 times. In few restarts it should stop trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just don't want the service to restart like 900 or 1000 times. In few restarts, it should stop trying...

Say, you want to do something (by the program runs inside the pod) which requires a couple of retries but you also don't want it to retry an infinite number of times.

In such a case, I will recommend you to handle it from inside the program instead of handling it from the pod's restart.

Wrap your task inside a retries loop with a timeout/maxRetries:

```
Algo:

 - Retries until timeout/maxRetires:
   - Do your job
 - end loop
```

**NB:** If you want your pod to terminate after completing the task, use k8s `Job` instead of Pod.